# How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'"

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to record a specific time of when a order is placed on my program.

```py
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import time

now = datetime.now()
lbltime1 = Label(master3, text="Current date and time: ")
lbltime1.pack()
lbltime2 = Label(master3, now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
lbltime2.pack()
```

I get the error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: you need `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.timestamp.now()` there. `datetime.timestamp` is a `<method 'timestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>`

Comment: Also, you just need one import `from datetime import datetime`. Then do `datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.timestamp` is a `method` of `datetime.datetime`. And since you have already `import`ed `datetime` from `datetime`, you only need to do

```
>>> now = datetime.now()
```

instead of,

```
>>> datetime.timestamp.now()
```

And then `format` with,

```
>>> now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2019-09-11 18:14:03'
```

And please fix the line,

```
>>> lbltime2 = Label(master3, now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

with

```
>>> lbltime2 = Label(master3, text=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The error happened, because you were not providing `text` `keyword`, that `Label` apparently seems to requires

Comment: Thank you, i have done this now get another error, "TypeError: must be str, not datetime.datetime." As said i'm extremely new to this.

Comment: Updated, please could you take a look and if you need more of the code i am willing to share.

Comment: I'm dreading your response but, as said i am EXTREMELY new to this and don't know what that is sorry, could you explain please?

Comment: You are a lifesaver my friend. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

datetime.timestamp() is a method that takes a datetime as a parameter.

But to get a human calendar style date entry like that, you don't need timestamp at all - just the current time, and use strftime() like you did:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.now()
now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

is:

```
'2019-09-11 15:44:25'
```